Partial interception of default XML serialization C#
I am trying to create an XML object serialization base class to accumulate a bunch of stuff that I've learned over the past few years, to have a ready to use example whenever I need it.
I want to add Xml comment functionality, and have found some stackoverflow post that helps me in that. With a bit of cleanup, here is what my code looks like:
// XmlComment attribute class
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class XmlCommentAttribute(string value) : Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = value;
}

// Usage in code
[XmlComment("This is an example comment that describes the name.")]
[XmlComment("Second comment line")]
public string Name { get; set; }

// Added code to satisfy IXmlSerializable
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    var properties = GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        if (HasCommentAttribute(propertyInfo))
            HandleCommentAttribute(writer, propertyInfo);
 
        writer.WriteElementString(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(this).ToString());
    }
}

private static bool HasCommentAttribute(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) 
    => propertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(XmlCommentAttribute), false);

private static void HandleCommentAttribute(XmlWriter writer, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var comments = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlCommentAttribute), false);

    foreach (var comment in comments)
        if (comment is XmlCommentAttribute line)
            writer.WriteComment($" {line.Value} ");
}

Serialization result:
<!-- This is an example comment that describes the name. -->
<!-- Second comment line -->
<Name>John</Name>

Huray!, although, not quite. When I use the given WriteXml function, I run into issues where object do not serialize properly.
[XmlComment("This is an example comment that describes the name.")]
[XmlComment("Second comment line")]
public string Name { get; set; }

// Added class definition and property below
public class AttributeExample
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Attrib1 { get; set; } = ushort.MaxValue;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Attrib2 { get; set; } = byte.MaxValue;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Attrib3 { get; set; } = short.MaxValue;
}

public AttributeExample ExampleOfAttributedObject { get; set; }

This serializes to:
<!-- This is an example comment that describes the name. -->
<!-- Second comment line -->
<Name>John</Name>
<ExampleOfAttributedObject>ConfigurationPersistence.ExampleConfigObject2+AttributeExample</ExampleOfAttributedObject>

Which is not quite correct.
The problem lies in the fact that the WriteXml function parses my object to a string with the writer.WriteElementString(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(this).ToString()) function call.
How do I get this object, and any of its child objects to serialize properly, like the standard implementation of WriteXml? How does the XmlSerializer do this? You have to iterate over all properties, and that property's properties, and serialize every object's value.

UPDATE
With the help of @dbc, I was able to serialize the child objects properly. Here is my updated WriteXml() function.
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    var properties = GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (HasCommentAttribute(property))
            HandleCommentAttribute(writer, property);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(property.PropertyType);            
        serializer.Serialize(writer, property.GetValue(this));
    }
}

Object to serialize:
[Serializable]
public class ExampleConfigObject
{
    [XmlComment("This is an example comment that describes the name.")]
    [XmlComment("Second comment line")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "John";

    [XmlComment("This is another example comment")]
    public string Description { get; set; } = "Doe";

    public int Count { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;

    public class AttributeExample
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Attrib1 { get; set; } = ushort.MaxValue;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Attrib2 { get; set; } = byte.MaxValue;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Attrib3 { get; set; } = short.MaxValue;

        [XmlElement]
        public string Text { get; set; } = "Some text";
    }

    public AttributeExample ExampleOfAttributedObject { get; set; } = new();

    public List<string> ListOfStrings { get; set; } = ["Foo", "Bar"]
}

Output XML document:
<ExampleConfigObject>
    <!--This is an example comment that describes the name.-->
    <!--Second comment line-->
    <string>John</string>
    <!--This is another example comment-->
    <string>Doe</string>
    <int>2147483647</int>
    <AttributeExample
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        Attrib1="1"
        Attrib2="2"
        Attrib3="3">
        <Text>Some text</Text>
    </AttributeExample>
    <ArrayOfString
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <string>Foo</string>
        <string>Bar</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
</ExampleConfigObject>

Some more questions that arise now are:

Why are there these XMLSchema attributes on the child objects?
How do I avoid having to implement ReadXml too? I'm not interested in deserializing the comments and wish to just use the default XmlReader's implementation


Remove the items after the equal sign like = ushort.MaxValue;

Which is not quite correct: It's not clear what you consider to be correct. Please add the desired output to your post.

You will need to either implement IXmlSerializable on AttributeExample also, or invoke the serializer from within your WriteXml() method to serialize it automatically. (This is is approximately what XmlSerializer does.  It generates contracts for all declared types in the serialization graph in its constructor, then then when serializing an instance of the root type it uses those contracts to descend the serialization graph and serialize the encountered instances of referenced types.)

Incidentally you can make XmlSerializer generate comments, see this answer to How to write a comment to an XML file when using the XmlSerializer?.
